# Attempting to create a SUM with a CONCAT in the range, google sheets says no

Tags: excel, sum, formula, concatenation

I was wondering if you could help me with a request. I used a custom script that dynamically creates one half of a cell reference, and I use a ROW formula to calculate the other half of the reference. The problem is, I'm trying to use that generated reference in a SUM calculation, but I am having issues using the correct syntax.

In essence I'm trying to create a formula that I can drag down 112 columns and save myself having to do the same thing multiple times. The script I made uses the following formula to create the column letter:

(averageTimeCalculator(U88) - U88 is just a field I'm using for the sake of testing this formula out, and it works perfectly. The second half of the reference is created by just taking the row of whatever the formula itself is on, so in this case: 
ROW(Z88)

Using CONCAT I put the two together "=(CONCAT(averageTimeCalculator(U88),ROW(Z88)))" which gives me the result: F88. What I'm trying to do with that reference is find out the sum of all the values on that row, leading up to it, so in essence I'm trying to create a formula that represents =SUM(A88:F88), in a way that I can drag it from A:3 to A:114), but everything I have tried to this point has thrown some sort of parsing error.

I've been throwing myself at this problem for a few hours now, using variants of the following syntax:

=SUM((C88):CONCAT(averageTimeCalculator(U88),ROW(A88)))

but I can't get it to work :( can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SUM(INDIRECT(A89)) where cell A89 would contain the text "A88:F88".

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to use a variant of that formula to get it working :)